# how to show confirmation box on page refresh or page close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea in form. I want to show confirmation box when user close the window without save the content.

I have a code

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable
myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
    var confirmationMessage = ' ';  // a space
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
});
```

it works well. But i am getting the same confirmation box when i submit save button. How can i find whether submit button clicked or not?.

Thanks

Comment: Use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) when the save button is clicked

Comment: just initialize some flag on submit click and check

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies. I have tried all these ideas. But it does not work. I want to remove event Listener when i click submit button. So it should not ask any confirmation when i submit.

Comment: i found the solution here. thanks for the replies  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo2.htm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little tweaky, but you could create an event handler on the `submit` of the `form` and set a variable there to ignore the message to pop up.

```
<form onsubmit="disableMessagePopup()">
  ...
</form>
```